# How to read comma separated numbers from a file into an multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, fread, fseek

I want to write a function that creates arrays of integers in a file with comma separated numbers like this:

```
         1,    54520.00000,    86397.00000,   0
         2,    54440.00000,    87200.00000,   0
         3,    51280.00000,    97600.00000,   0
         4,    50000.00000,   100000.00000,   0
         5,    48880.00000,   100000.00000,   0
```

The first column is the number of each row, so the data I need is actually the next three columns.
My problems are:

1. Since I don't know the dimension of the array, I have to first read the first number of the last row. How to do that? I tried to use fseek to point my file pointer to the end of the file and then find the previous '\n', but I don't know how to deal with comma.
2. After I get the number of rows, how can I read those data I need into a N_row*3 array? How to deal with comma and '\n'?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The number of columns is fixed?

Comment: Yes, the number of columns is fixed.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate"?

Comment: Means that someone else has asked this question before and there's probably an answer already somewhere on this site

Comment: You mean for example this one (second or third of the whole page I got when I searched for "comma separated read in C").
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709804/read-comma-separated-numbers-from-a-file-in-c

Comment: I see. This is my first time to ask question on this website. I read that question as well, but I can't understand the idea. I'm sorry for asking duplicate questions. Next time I will search similar questions first. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `fscanf()`

use the following `fscanf()` into a loop till you reach the end of the file:

```
int i,j
double x,y;
while (fscanf(fp, " %d , %f , %f , %d", &i, &x, &y, &j) != EOF) {....}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I assign x, y, j to myarray[i][0], myarray[i[1], myarray[i][2] respectively in the while loop? I just tried that but it didn't work:(

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It works very well! Thank you very much! By the way, can you give me a hint on my first question about how to read the first number of the last column?

Comment: You don't need this part "%*[^\n]". Just read the next "%d" and '\n' will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you Mohamed KALLEL and  Alex Oliveira. It's the simplest way to tackle my problem I've ever seen.